# one scatter plot for 3 scatter point group

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am new to R. I have a problem that has been bothering me for days. 
I have 3 groups of data.

```
set.seed(1)
x1 = runif(30, 0, 7)
y1 = runif(30, 0, 7)
x2 = runif(30, 10, 20)
y2 = runif(30, 10, 20)
x3 = runif(30, 0, 7)
y3 = runif(30, 10, 20)
```

I would like to know how to plot those 3 groups of scatter points on the same x-y graph and with different color?

Answer (score 0):

```
xy <- data.frame(X = c(x1,x2,x3), 
             Y = c(y1,y2,y3),
             Group = factor(rep(1:3, each = 30)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(xy, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = Group))
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution with base R can be:

```
plot(x1, y1, xlim = c(0,20), ylim = c(0,20))
lines(x2, y2, type = "p", col = "red")
lines(x3, y3, type = "p", col = "green")
```